# Improper integral with upper limit infinite

Tags: integration

What is the value of $$\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt{x-1}}{(x+1)^2}dx?$$

I have tried substituion $y=x+1$ and integration by parts but failed. Then another substitution $x=\sec^2 y$, but again did not proceed. Can anybody help me with this integration?

Comment: Substitution gives the integral is equivalent to $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^2}{(u^2+2)^2} \mathrm{d}u$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

By the change of variable
$$
\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{2}\cdot\tan \theta,\quad x+1=2\left(1+\tan^2\theta \right),
$$ one gets
$$
\int_1^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt{x-1}}{(x+1)^2}dx=\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 \theta \:d\theta
$$ which is easier to evaluate.